# How do i add an H1 tag to this echo output?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, tags, echo

I am having trouble adding an `h1` tag to to the output of this echo. The echo is inside a larger function in my Wordpress install.

The code is part of a larger function. I've tried to enclose the echo statement in `h1` tag with single quotes and double quotes. I've also tried to separate the echo inside another PHP wrapper.

```php
<?php if ( is_tax( 'wap8-portfolio-tags' ) ) { // adds tag name to title block
        $term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var('taxonomy'));
        echo $term->name;
    }
```

I'd like to see the echo output the variable with `h1` styling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work

```
echo '<h1>' . $term->name . '</h1>';
```

Comment: Yes, that was it.  Thanks!  I'll have to learn more about those dots.  What do those dots do in this case?

Comment: The manual:  it's your best friend. 
 https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Comment: the dots are to add text to text , see the examples in the link mentioned by Tim